# How to remove file name from cmd NOTEPAD /P

Tags: c++, command-line, scripting, notepad

I have a command line being executed in my C++ code that states:

`CString sCmd = "NOTEPAD /P myfile.txt";`
`WinExec(sCmd, SW_HIDE);`

The file prints out but at the top of each page is the text, centered, "myfile.txt", next line the beginning of my file text.

Is there a way to eliminate the file title on each page of the print out and/or at least but a blank line between the title and the beginning of the text?

Thanks

Comment: This seems more like a question regarding notepad, not C++ code

Comment: My point is, it could be considered off-topic

Comment: 'off-topic' to what? Clarify what your talking about.

Comment: As in, off-topic for StackOverflow. For now, I'll leave the question open.

Comment: Why would this be off topic for StackOverflow even if it was a NotePade question? Though it is not the notepad exe file is called from a Windows carll 'WinExec' that can call any outside app. Maybe someone knows of a way to manipulate the app calls via WinExec, maybe someone knows of a better print app to use, ... etc. And who are you to determine if the question should be left open?

Comment: That's why I said I'm not sure if it's off-topic. Now that I've thought about it, the only change necessary was to add a "notepad" tag (since you mention it in the title and the body). And while I can't close it by myself, I can certainly vote to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

There is no command line option for Notepad that will change or remove the page header. Notepad will remember your configured page settings though, so you could start Notepad manually, set header and footer in Page Setup, quit, then program will print using your presets.

Or, why not just use the Windows `print` console tool, instead of Notepad?

```
WinExec("cmd.exe /c print /d:\\servername\printername filename.txt", SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the printing of the file has to generic. Meaning this app can be on any PC at any site so the 'printername' is unknown at time of compile whereas the 'NOTEPAD' way prints to what every the default printer is set at on the running PC.